# Error message: Unable to locate ADB inspite of several attempts in rectifying

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools, platform-tools

I am getting an alert message when I try to start an android virtual device from the AVD Manager, which is shown as below

[image: AVD Error].

Below are some of the action I tried in rectifying this issue based on my search on the web and all of them have not helped me in fixing this error so far.

- Tried reinstalling Android studio to assure of no issues during installations
- Tried reinstalling the platform-tools from the SDK Manager -> SDK Tools
- Tried reinstalling the platform-tools offline by downloading the platform-tools from the android website (same version)
- Uninstalled anti-virus and tried starting the virtual device but whitelisting the adb.exe on the windows firewall
- No space in the Android SDK path
- Futile attempts in running Android Studio as administrator
- Tried cold boot also on a virtual device but no success

**What confuses me is that the virtual device starts inspite of this alert message. Upon closing the virtual device, I get an error with the description as below in the event log**

> Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))

**Device file explorer message as below**

[image: Device file explorer message]

Do I have to try something else to rectify this? Appreciate any help in this regard. Would be happy to help if any more info required. Thanks in advance

Additionally, My windows device location is enabled. So, location should not be an issue